# How can i lock statistics (analyze) of tables in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

How can i lock statistics (analyze) of tables in postgresql?

There is a scheduled job truncates and inserts data into a table.( Size more than 1 gb).
Truncating the table causes the statistic to change. Then, a query using this table as a source gives undesired execution plan and takes too much time.

If i analyze the table manually, the duration of the query decreases acceptable time.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that.

If the scheduled job performs mass data modification, it had better run an explicit `ANALYZE` when it is done (and a `VACUUM` wouldn't hurt either).

It does not make much sense to keep the statistics when you truncate a table and insert new data into it.